# Would it be i-Kiribati or I-Kiribati?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization, demonyms

So the demonym of Kiribati is "i-Kiribati". Apart from being cool, what is the correct way of writing this? Would it be a capital "I" all the time? eg. "I'm an I-Kiribati" or would it be a small "i" depending on the sentence of course eg. "I'm an i-Kiribati".

A similar question can be asked for the Maldives. Is it the Maldives or The Maldives?

Comment: What does your research tell you? Five minutes of internetting fished up several instances of *I-Kiribati* and none of the lower case variety.  Is this really an English question? Or is it something about *ni Kiribati*?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

As an I-Kiribati I will always use "I-Kiribati".  For as far as I know since pre-school till graduating from college, we always use I-Kiribati just like using our name... e.g My name's David (not david).